# Cannot open website link in J2ME

Tags: java, http, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am working on a simple J2ME application and i have  a StringItem linked to a terms and conditions page online.

I have the StringItem setup and it appears underlined (giving the feeling that it is linked); but when i click on it, it does not perform any action.

Find below my code:

```
public class mobiMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    private Display display;
    private TextField userName,password;
    public Form form;
    private Command login, register, forgot, terms, cancel;
    private Image img_error, img_login, img_register, img_forgot, img_terms;
    private String termsurl = "http://example.com/terms.php";
    private StringItem termsItem;

    public mobiMidlet() {
          form = new Form("Welcome to My App");

          termsItem = new StringItem("", "Terms and Conditions", Item.HYPERLINK);
          termsItem.setDefaultCommand(new Command("terms", Command.ITEM, 1));    

            ItemCommandListener listener = new ItemCommandListener() {
                    public void commandAction(Command cmd, Item item) {
                        if(cmd==terms)
                        {
                            try {
                                platformRequest(termsurl);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

            termsItem.setItemCommandListener(listener);        

          userName = new TextField("LoginID:", "", 30, TextField.ANY);
          password = new TextField("Password:", "", 30, TextField.PASSWORD);
          cancel = new Command("Cancel", Command.CANCEL, 2);
          login = new Command("Login", Command.OK, 2);
          try{
            img_login = Image.createImage("/logo.jpg");
            img_register = Image.createImage("/error2.png");
            img_forgot = Image.createImage("/logo.jpg");
            img_register = Image.createImage("/error2.png");
          }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }  
    }


    public void startApp() {
          display = Display.getDisplay(this);
          form.append(termsItem);
          form.append(userName);
          form.append(password);
          form.addCommand(cancel);
          form.addCommand(login);
          form.setCommandListener(this);
          display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
          String label = c.getLabel();
          if(label.equals("Cancel")) {
              destroyApp(true);
          } else if(label.equals("Login")) {
            validateUser(userName.getString(), password.getString());
          } 
    }
}
```

How can I fix this so that when I click on the terms and conditions link, it opens the page on a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized variable `terms`, so it remains `null`. Therefore condition `cmd==terms` is always `false` and you never enter the `if` statement.

Separate line `termsItem.setDefaultCommand(new Command("terms", Command.ITEM, 1));` to two:

```
terms = new Command("terms", Command.ITEM, 1);
termsItem.setDefaultCommand(terms);
```

Now you have a chance. 
BTW why not to debug you program? Run it in emulator, put break point into `commandAction` and see what happens.